# Deploying UWP to remote device

Tags: uwp

I am learning UWP and would like to develop Apps on a laptop and remote deploy them on a Surface Pro6. I am unable find a solution and would appreciate if someone can help. I can write small Apps but cannot deploy on a remote device.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually got it to run. First, you must have Visual Studio Remote Tools installed on the remote machine (I found you need it on both machines).
Enable Developers mode (Systems/for Developers) on development machine and on remote machine.
Make sure your certificate for you App is yours (not from an example code copied from internet, I ran into permission issues, even after I deleted and recreated a new one).

Then from Visual Studio, select Project/Properties, the select Debug. Enter Remote machine information. Click on the Find button. (Make sure Visual Studio Remote Tools is running on the remote device.)
I had issues with authentication, so I had to set Authentication Mode to None (which is not safe???) on development and remote machine. They should be same on both machines.
Now you can select Debug, type of deployment (x64 for example) and click on Remote Machine.
I created a very simple HelloWorld app to iron out deployment issues. It finally worked after days of trying.